# Valuation ring which is not a DVR but has finite residue field

Tags: commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, valuation-theory, local-rings

Is there an example of a complete valuation ring $(R, m)$ which is not a DVR but such that $R/m$ is finite?
Examples of valuation rings I have in mind are ring of integers of finite extensions of $\Bbb Q_p$, but those are DVR, or $\Bbb C_p$ but the residual field is infinite...

Thank you very much!

Comment: The valuation ring of the field of Hahn series $\Bbb F_q[[T^{\Bbb Q}]]$ should do the trick.

Comment: In general there's a recipe for constructing a valuation with any prescribed value group and residue field. See my answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3415695/valuation-rings-only-have-two-prime-ideals/3581762#3581762. Using the notation of the above answer, start with any finite $\mathtt{k}$ and arbitrary $\Gamma$,.where $\Gamma$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Since completion is immediate, the completion of $\mathtt{k} ((t^{\Gamma}))$ should work.